# Cambiar el tamaño de una label en Pygal

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quisiera saber como puedo cambiar el tamaño de label de un grafico en pygal, intente estas 2 cosas:

**Utilizando un estilo predefinido NeonStyle**

```
visual = pygal.Line(style=NeonStyle(value_font_size=18))
```

**Utilizando un CustomStyle**

```
custom = Style(value_font_size=18)
visual = pygal.Line(style=custom)
```

Este es el codigo completo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import pygal
from pygal.style import NeonStyle



class Graf(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("otros_graficos.ui",self)
        custom = Style(
            value_font_size=50,
        )


        self.grafico = QWebEngineView(self.widget)
        self.grafico.resize(self.width(),self.widget.height())
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.grafico)

        visual = pygal.Line(style=custom)
        visual.title="Reporte Anual"
        visual.x_labels= ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"]
        visual.add("title", [1,2,3,4,5])
        visual.x_label_rotation=50

        data = visual.render_data_uri()
        self.grafico.load(QUrl(data))

app = QApplication([])
g = Graf()
g.show()
app.exec_()
visual = pygal.Line(style=custom)
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con label?

Comment: @eyllanesc, las labels por ejemplo "Enero","Febrero"

Comment: ya publique una respuesta, por otro lado te recomiendo evitar usar un .ui en tu codigo, por ejemplo yo lo he eliminado, ya que tu ejemplo no es un [mcve] si tiene partes no definidas :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar `label_font_size`, si quieres personalizar otras propiedades en [este enlace](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/custom_styles.html?highlight=font#properties) hay una tabla que señalan las propiedades.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import pygal
from pygal.style import Style


class Graf(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Graf, self).__init__()
        custom = Style(
            label_font_size=30,
        )

        self.grafico = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.grafico)
        visual = pygal.Line(style=custom)
        visual.title ="Reporte Anual"
        visual.x_labels = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"]
        visual.add("title", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        visual.x_label_rotation = 50

        data = visual.render_data_uri()
        self.grafico.load(QtCore.QUrl(data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    g = Graf()
    g.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]